# How to pair with an unbound peripheral who's still bound in Windows

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my Windows 10 UWP C# Bluetooth Low Energy application :

If the device (peripheral) has never been paired, I can successfully pair the device from the central (Windows UWP) with the BluetoothLeDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing API.

Once paired, both side store their bonding information so that pairing is no more needed. On the next connection, pairing returns with "AlreadyPaired" status and connection works fine.

If I remove the bonding information on the central side (Windows), pairing returns with "Paired" status and connection works fine.

If I remove the bonding information on the peripheral side (and not the central side), pairing returns with "AlreadyPaired" status, but the connection wont work as the peripheral has no bonding information. How can I detect if peripheral has no bonding inforamtion any more and/or how can I "force" pairing without unpairing (remove bonding inforamtion) the Windows side ?

Comment: Have you tried `DeviceInformationPairing.UnpairAsync` method? Afther that you can try the `DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync` method.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing now as a workaround. And to know if I have to unpair I try to make a characteristic access. But this is far not the best solution.